# How to Add Profile Blue tick in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, profile

I am developing a app, and want to provide some users blue tick on profile, how it can be done, I'm using java for development and firebase.
Please help

Comment: Please do some research over this and then ask a question here. Questions without any research are not acceptable here.

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm getting this right. You want to have some verified users which will have a blue tick.

To do this just add an imageview beside the textView showing the Name of the user which I'm guessing you're getting from firebase.
Then in your firebase the profile could have a flag like `isVerifiedUser` depending on which you make the visibility of the imageview as View.VISIBLE or View.GONE